# Lebesgue Convergence Theorem: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^\infty\frac{2n}{e^{2x}+n^2x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Find

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_1^\infty \frac{2n}{e^{2x}+n^2x}dx$$

I'm having trouble finding the right function to bound $f_n$ with. Clearly $f_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ so the integral is going to end up being zero. I'm thinking the function is bounded by $\frac{2}{e^2}$ which might be enough. Is this sufficient?

Comment: No, $2/e^2$ is insufficient because it's not integrable on $[1, \infty)$.

Comment: Also I don't think that those functions bounded by that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not Ok, and the integrand $2/e^2$ does not give a convergent integral over $[1,\infty)$.

Observe that, by the AGM inequality,
$$
0\le\frac{2n}{e^{2x}+n^2x}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{x \,e^{2x}}}\le\frac{1}{e^{x}},\quad x\ge1
$$ which is integrable over $[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use $e^{2x}\geq 4x^3$ for any $x\geq 1$, ensuring
$$ 0\leq \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{2n}{e^{2x}+n^2 x}\,dx \leq\frac{1}{n}\log\left(1+\frac{n^2}{4}\right)$$
so that you don't even need the DCT.